# CMake option naming convention for conditional parts/dependencies?

Tags: cmake, idioms, cmakelists-options

Is there a commonly-accepted convention regarding the naming of CMake options that indicate: "Depend on a certain package and build code utilizing that dependency"? And the same question for "Build this optional piece of the code"?

I see different projects using:

- `WITH_FOO`
- `USING_FOO`
- `ENABLE_FOO`
- `BUILD_FOO`

with either the first or the second kind of semantics, and I'm confused about what to choose for what.